# In which region of $\Bbb C$ is the function $f :z\mapsto \log(z + 1)$ differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

In which region of $\Bbb C$ is the function $f :z\mapsto \log(z + 1)$ differentiable?

(Remember that $\log(w) = \ln|w| + i \text{arg}(w)$,
 where $\text{arg} (w) ∈ [0, 2π)$

The solution is $\Bbb C \backslash \{z = x + iy : x ≥ −1, y = 0\}$

However, my resolution was:

$$\log(z+1)$$ 
$$= \ln|x+iy+1|+i(\text{arg}(x+iy+1)+2k\pi)$$ 
$$= \ln(\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}) + i(\text{arg}(x+iy+1)+2k\pi)$$

So $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}>0 \Longleftrightarrow x\neq-1$ and $y\neq0$

arg is discontinuos at pi/-pi and 0/2pi . So the function is continuous in C\y=0,x∈R In a circle with radius 1 (trigonometrical circle) -1<=x <= 1

So $f$ is differenciable in $\Bbb C \backslash \{z = x + iy : −1<=x<=1, y = 0\}$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: Think where $arg$ is continuous. Somewhere on the circle you need to jump, due to the condition that is lies between $0$ and $$2\pi$.

Comment: Is in pi/2 and 3pi/2 ? Sorry but i can't get it

Comment: Severin Schraven

Comment: I guess you want $arg(z)\in (-\pi,\pi]$. Anyway, the point is, that $\arg$ is discontinuous where it jumps from $\pi$ to $-\pi$ (respectively from $2\pi$ to zero). Thus, it is discontinuous on a halfline (usually we pick the halfline $(-\infty,0]$). Therefore, $\log(z)$ is holomorphic except for that halfline (then $\log(1+z)$ is holomorphic on the translated halfline).

Comment: Ok but so i got arg(z)∈[−π,π[ <=> -1<y/(x+1) < 1 <=> x belongs to [-1-y,y-1] . How leads this me to x>= -1 ?

Comment: You should look up the definition of $\arg$. I have no clue what you are doing, but the $\arg$ function assigns to a complex number its angle. For example $\arg(z)=0$ implies that $z\in (0, \infty)$.

Comment: Ok now i understand why x>= -1 , but since arg(z) is also discontinuos in 2pi to 0 shouldn't be the answer  C∖{z=x+iy:1≥x≥−1,y=0} ?

Comment: Show us how you reached that conclusion. Then we can help you to point out your mistake.

Comment: I read again your answers and i guess that makes more sense : arg is discontinuos at pi/-pi and 0/2pi . So the function is continuous in C\y=0,x∈R. And could you explain better what you mean when you said " Thus, it is discontinuous on a halfline (usually we pick the halfline (−∞,0]). Therefore, log(z) is holomorphic except for that halfline (then log(1+z) is holomorphic on the translated halfline)." I didn't understand it well

Comment: All of this is useless if you don't show us how you reached those conclusions. Add them in your question.